# update all result set with phalcon orm

Tags: resultset, phalcon

i try to update all result set with phalcon orm at once. like this:

```
foreach ($packages as $package) {
                $rates =  $package->getRates();
                $package->rates = $rates;
                $package->update();
                $packageHistory = PackageHistories::find('rates = 0 AND package_id = '.$package->id);
                $packageHistory->rates = $rates;
                $packageHistory->update();
            }
```

but it's not working. how should it looks like??

Comment: What is not updating? `$package` or `$packageHistory` or both? Have you tried outputting the errors ?

Comment: *"but it's not working."* - What is it currently doing to what you expect it should do?

Comment: on sql will be like this: "update packagesHistory set rates = 100 where rates = 0 and package_id = 10".
i know that code can use foreach function. but is there any style to update all data at once(without foreach)??. like bulk delete on phalcon.

Comment: What do you get if you execute `$packageHistory->getMessages()` after update?

Comment: What is the value in `$rates`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer:

```
foreach ($packages as $package) {
   $rates =  $package->getRates();
   $package->rates = $rates;
   $package->update();
   $packageHistory = PackageHistories::find('rates = 0 AND package_id = '.$package->id)->update(array('rates' => $rates));
}
```